# Why is there a pass statement in python?

Tags: python, indentation

In Python you use the pass statement so that the compiler does not raise an error on an empty block:

```py
#wrong example
if True:

print("hello")
```

This will give an `IndentationError`. So we use the pass statement instead

```py
#correct example
if True:
  pass
print("hello")
```

The above would be the normal use of pass. However, you could as well use the empty string as a placeholder:

```py
if True:
  ""
print("hello")
```

This version works exactly like a pass statement. It is readable for a human and says that this block is empty.
From this I would conclude that the pass statement really is redundant.

Comment: `...` is also a common stand-in for `pass`. But `pass` is explicitly for this purpose. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @khelwood You are totally right. But `""` and especially `...` are quite explicit. Also, is the explicity really reason enough to use a whole keyword that blocks variable names that coders might want to use?

Comment: If you're asking whether it's a good idea, that's a matter of opinion. But perhaps if `...` had existed at the time, `pass` would not have been included in the language.

Answer (score 1):

pass is here in order to have a clean way of doing it when prototyping there are plenty of others way to avoid an indentation error with an empty statement but `pass` is simply the clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter does not ignore a pass statement, but nothing happens and the statements result into no operation. When the pass statement is executed, you avoid getting an error when empty code is not allowed.

In your example it works fine.